# Why can't we use computation history to detect looping of a Turing machine on a given input?

Tags: computability, undecidability

First of all, obviously there is a flaw in my logic and I just want to know what it is.
So here is my idea: Given a TM M and an input string ω, simulate M on ω on another TM S. For every change of state on M record the TM's configuration. On all iterations compare the new configuration to every other recorded configuration. If there was a match, then the TM is surely not going to halt, at which point we stop the computation and accept or reject accordingly.

Comment: What happens if I give it a machine with one state that always writes $1$ to the current cell, moves the head right, and stays in the single state?

Comment: Your question is not explicit, so I assume it is "why doesn't this an algorithm solve the halting problem" (or something similar), to which the answer would be: your algorithm might never end.

Comment: A machine may run forever without looping.

Answer (score 6):

Detecting whether a machine $M$ is *looping* (meaning that it has reached the same configuration (**not only of its internal state but also of the tape**) twice), is indeed as "easy" as recording the configurations as we simulate $M$ and checking whether the current one was already seen.

This method is of course incapable of deciding whether a machine *will eventually loop*, but rather it detects looping only once it happens, which means that such procedure never tells you *the machine won't ever loop*; only that *it hasn't looped yet*. Note that this is same thing that occurs with the halting problem; it's easy to tell that a machine has halted; the hard part is deciding **whether a machine will eventually halt or not**.

It is worth noting as well that even though **looping $\implies$ not halting**, it's not true that **not halting $\implies$ looping**; for instance a Turing Machine listing all prime numbers on its tape will never halt and yet also never loop...

Answer (score 4):

This method will not detect

```
n:= 0;
while true do
  n:= n+1
```

so it is not universal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems: One, a Turing machine doesn't necessarily halt. That's because it has unlimited amounts of state. Your PC with 128 GB of RAM = 1 Terabit only has $2^{1024 \cdot 1024 \cdot 1024 \cdot 1024}$ different states, so it has to reach the same state again.

Two, if you simulate the Turing machine and you havent detected the same state after a year or after a trillion years then you don't know if you will eventually find a repeating state or not.

Comment: I guess that the OP's argument is "the machine will return to the same state sooner or later". There lies the flaw.